# RaphaelJS freeTransform IE

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-7, transform, raphael

*I'm trying to make a tool that transforms image (rotate, resize, later crop). This should work also in IE7. I decided to use **RaphaelJS**.*

There was some problems when I used rotation because the axis moved, later I've found that there is a plugin **freeTransform** that does exactly what I needed. Unfortunately this function seems to break in IE7, the image starts to act strange *(repeat itself see the jsFiddle example)*. It works in other browsers.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Ef83k/43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform/issues/2) on the [plugin's page on github](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform/issues/2). It seems to work in IE7 when `keepRatio` is set to `true`. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3BBJ/).

```
paper.freeTransform(img, {keepRatio: true});​
```